# Testcontainers warning that cannot be fixed

Tags: java, spring-boot, testcontainers

Wrote a @Testcontainers test in Junit 5 with Springboot 3. The test runs and passes, but I have the following warning:

```
'MySQLContainer<SELF>' used without 'try'-with-resources statement
```

But the code shows in fact the container is NOT used outside the try with resources statement:

```java
@Testcontainers
public class PageTemplateCreationTestContainerTests {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PageTemplateCreationTestContainerTests.class);

    @Test
    void mySQLContainerShouldBeRunning() {
        try (
                var mySQLContainer = new MySQLContainer<>("mysql:8.0")
                        .withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(logger))
        ) {
            mySQLContainer.start();
            assertThat(mySQLContainer.isRunning(), is(true));
        }
    }
}
```

I read through the docs for Autocloseable and of course there's no help here from IntelliJ. Thought maybe it was choking on the `var` syntax but no.

This warning should not appear.

Comment: What's the _question_? Be specific; StackOverflow is a Q&A platform.

Comment: Does it work without the `.withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(logger))`?

Comment: @dan1st bingo, make an answer out of it and I will check mark it.. #everythingisbroken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: It's a false positive due to the `.withLogConsumer()` chained call.

IntelliJ shows you that `new MySQLContainer<>("mysql:8.0")` is not closed by the try-with-resources block. Instead, you are calling `.withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(logger))` on it and closing that using try-with-resources.

Since closing the object returned by `.withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(logger))` also closes the `MySQLContainer` ([it is the same objects as it returns `this`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.testcontainers/testcontainers/latest/index.html), this is a false positive.

If you want to get around this error without suppressing it, you could try to close both resources (which is what IntelliJ wants from you):

```java
        try (
                var containerWithoutLogger = new MySQLContainer<>("mysql:8.0");
                var mySQLContainer = containerWithoutLogger.withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(logger))
        ) {
            mySQLContainer.start();
            assertThat(mySQLContainer.isRunning(), is(true));
        }
```

However, this would close it twice. Alternatively, you could try to call `withLogConsumer` inside the try-block but that might result in a similar warning being shown at that point.

```java
        try (
                var mySQLContainer = new MySQLContainer<>("mysql:8.0");
        ) {
            mySQLContainer.withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(logger));
            mySQLContainer.start();
            assertThat(mySQLContainer.isRunning(), is(true));
        }
```

Comment: Yeah I tried doing that but did not remove the warning, lemme try that again. Sounds like you did not try it? ok that worked, thanks.

Comment: Since I currently do not use IntelliJ, I didn't test it and Idon't know its exact behaviour by heart. However, you could probably also suppress the warning.